# Variable coefficient and term differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following variable coefficient and term differential equation:
￼￼￼
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + 4ty=4t$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write it as $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1 - y} = 4t \ \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Can you please expand

Comment: Maybe if you show some effort (:

Comment: I'm really lost, do you have a website you can refer me to please

Comment: This is a separable differential equation, meaning you can write the equation as $g(y) y'(t) = f(t)$ or, equivalently, $g(y) dy = f(t) dt$. Does this sound familiar?